# polynomial with root 1 with multiplicity at least n

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Prove or disprove the following:

For any positive integer n, there exists a polynomial $P_n$ of degree $n^2$ such that

(1) all coefficients of $P_n$ are integers with absolute value at most $n^2$, and

(2) 1 is a root of $P_n=0$ with multiplicity at least n.

I try to solve this problem by synthetic division or  mathematical induction but I failed
So I don't know how I do.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you expecting an explicit or inexplicit construction?

Comment: I just want to solve this problem so I don't care of explicit or implicit construction. Thank you about the comments